# C# MySQL Update boolean

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-update, boolean

This is my Database Class, my Aim is to block a users(personeel) Cardnumber(pasnummer) I believe my Sql query is correct.

```
 public Personeel BlockPersoneel(bool iGeblokkeerd)
    {
        OpenDeConnectie();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `personeel` SET `Geblokkeerd` = '1' WHERE `Pasnummer` = @pasnummer", DatabaseConnectie);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pasnummer", iGeblokkeerd);

        MySqlDataReader reader;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();
        Personeel personeel = new Personeel();
        personeel.Geblokkeerd = reader.GetBoolean("Geblokkeerd");

        return personeel;
    }
```

This is my main form(ParkeerSysteem) my aim here is to make sure that btBlokkeren_click will execute whaetever is in BlockPersoneel. I have tried to change a few things here and there, I think im missing something or not using the right paths to make this one do what I want it to do.

```
        private void btBlokkeren_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // im having a hard time figuring out how to execute my db.BlockPersoneel database class method
        // I have tried a few lines of codes with no results
        Personeel personeel = db.BlockPersoneel(personeel.Geblokkeerd());

        // I have tried this aswell with no result

        Personeel personeel = new Personeel();

        personeel.Geblokkeerd = true;
    }
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your query is not correct. If the field is a boolean then don't set it using a string '1' but directly with a numeric value of 1 or 0.

After that, using an `MySqlDataReader` on an UPDATE query is meaningless because the UPDATE doesn't return the row changed. You need a SELECT.

```
public Personeel BlockPersoneel(bool iGeblokkeerd)
{
    OpenDeConnectie();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `personeel` SET `Geblokkeerd` = 1 WHERE `Pasnummer` = @pasnummer", DatabaseConnectie);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pasnummer", iGeblokkeerd);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Use the same command but change the commandtext to retrieve the record
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT `Geblokkeerd` FROM `personeel` WHERE `Pasnummer` = @pasnummer";
    // Use ExecuteScalar because we need only the value 
    // from the first column of the first row
    bool blocked = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    personeel.Geblokkeerd = blocked;
    return personeel;
}
```

However, because the call to ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by the command, you could be sure that your row has been updated if the return of ExecuteNonQuery is bigger than zero

```
public Personeel BlockPersoneel(bool iGeblokkeerd)
{
    OpenDeConnectie();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `personeel` SET `Geblokkeerd` = 1 WHERE `Pasnummer` = @pasnummer", DatabaseConnectie);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pasnummer", iGeblokkeerd);
    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    personeel.Geblokkeerd = (rows > 0);
    return personeel;
}
```

Not related to your actual problem, but that `OpenDeConnectie()` method seems to be a sure source of troubles. If you open the connection there when do you close it? A connection shouldn't be kept open for the lifetime of your application. It consumes server and local resources and its state creates a series of logical problems that you need to handle everytime you try to use it (And not to mention what could happen if you get some exception that change the normal flow of your code)